# Can't find log file on server using log4j

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-mvc, log4j

I am trying to configure log4j for the first time but its not creating myTest.log file. Below is my log4j.properties file and location of this file is WEB-INF/classes folder.

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, com.myTest

#tomcat logger
#log4j.logger.org.apache.catalina=DEBUG

log4j.logger.com.myTest=INFO

log4j.logger.org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration=DEBUG

#appenders
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=[%5p] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %m%n

log4j.appender.com.myTest=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender 
log4j.appender.com.myTest.File=myTest.log 
log4j.appender.com.myTest.MaxFileSize=15MB 
log4j.appender.com.myTest.MaxBackupIndex=10 
log4j.appender.com.myTest.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 
log4j.appender.com.myTest.layout.ConversionPattern=[%5p] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %m%n

log4j.appender.org.apache.ibatis=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender 
log4j.appender.org.apache.ibatis.File=myTest.log 
log4j.appender.org.apache.ibatis.MaxFileSize=15MB 
log4j.appender.org.apache.ibatis.MaxBackupIndex=10 
log4j.appender.org.apache.ibatis.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 
log4j.appender.org.apache.ibatis.layout.ConversionPattern=[%5p] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}     %m%n
```

My controller class is like

```
@Controller
public class LoginController
{
static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LoginController.class);

@RequestMapping("/login")
public ModelAndView login(){

    logger.debug("Test logs");
    logger.error("test error");

    return new ModelAndView("login"); 

}

 }
```

But I can't see any myTest.log file in my Apache/log folder. Is this a place it should be?

Jar file I am using is log4j-1.2.16.jar. Is anything else required.

I am using Ubuntu and its first time I am using this.

Comment: did you look into the root directory of your application, too?

Comment: Search ur computer for myTest.log I once found logging where I didnt expect it could be :)

Comment: Jenson I am new to ubuntu so when I click on root directory it says you do not have permission to see this folder. How I can go to root by using terminal window?

Comment: in the log4j.properties, you have to set the full path to your log file. Ex: `log4j.appender.com.myTest.File=${catalina.home}/log/myTest.log`

Comment: @user965884 place the log4j.properties file within `src` folder

Comment: @user965884 no, im talking about the directory, where yourn Spring Application is in

Comment: @Alexander: Yes, your suggestion helped me, since i located my log file in eclipse logs folder. Dont know why it went in there though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put log4j.properties file in build/classes/ folder.

Put file path to ${catalina.home}/logs/myTest.log.

```
  log4j.appender.com.myTest.File=${catalina.home}/log/myTest.log
```

Path of logs can be checked by writing below code in your LoginController class

```
    Enumeration e = Logger.getRootLogger().getAllAppenders();
    while ( e.hasMoreElements() ){
      Appender app = (Appender)e.nextElement();
     if ( app instanceof FileAppender ){
    System.out.println("File: " + ((FileAppender)app).getFile());
  }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

As you have **posted** in your question the **location** of `log4j.properties` file is `WEB-INF/classes` folder.

To solve the issue try placing the `log4j.properties` file within `src` folder of your application.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem。 
On the server machine,log4j could't write log file, but used standout to print log info， it is working.(do you?)
I think is the permissions problem.
so i write log file in tomcat log location(logs/)

```
log4j.appender.com.myTest.File=${catalina.home}/logs/myTest.log
```

Hope this works for you！！